# Twitter API - Post status / tweet on behalf of user

Tags: laravel, twitter

In my app, a user signs in with Twitter OAuth, that's all fine. I store their access token and secret. I am using Laravel.

I want to post a tweet on their behalf at certain points. In the docs, the endpoint I need is - 'statuses/update'.

For authentication, the docs simply say - "Requires authentication? Yes (user context only)"

I can't seem to find much on exactly "user context" authentication means and what I need to send with the request. I am a real newbie with OAuth.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!!

So far I've got:

```
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'base_uri' => 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/'
    ]);


    $response = $client->request('POST', 'statuses/update.json', [
        'status' => 'Whats up',
            'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$user->token,
        ]
    ]);
```

Getting back:

"Client error: `POST https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json` resulted in a `401 Authorization Required` response:↵{"errors":[{"code":89,"message":"Invalid or expired token."}]}↵"

Cheers!

Comment: Could you show us some of the code you've written? And, if possible, any error message you've got.

Comment: You're trying to use a Bearer token here, which is what Twitter counts as "application-only" auth - you aren't able to post on behalf of a user with this setup. You need to present all four tokens (consumer key and secret, account token and account token secret) in the OAuth headers. See https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/authorizing-a-request

Answer (score 0):

sorry, but `Bearer` maybe only application auth

```
Bearer tokens allow for a more secure point of entry for developers to use the Twitter APIs. They are one of the core features of OAuth 2.0. Bearer tokens are a type of access token; authentication which uses bearer tokens is also known sometimes as application-only authentication or auth-only authentication.
```

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/bearer-tokens

You should use oauth 1.0 for user context
it mean use
`Oauth ....` for tweet as user
you can use library support generate `authorization` for add it to header
or try make by by hand follow this https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/creating-a-signature